# How do I perform a text search in mysql in multiple table selection

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have 2 pieces of the database, the database within it there are 5 tables, to do a text search with mysql I used to use

```
"SELECT * FROM myTable1 WHERE content LIKE '% helo%'".
```

and

```
"SELECT * FROM myTable2 WHERE text LIKE '% helo%'".
```

How to incorporate them into one.

Comment: If you let us know the schema of the tables and what result you are expecting, we have help you optimize your query as well.

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by Timofey Stolbov you can use Union Query, but do keep in mind that

> Union clause will removes duplicate rows between the two "select" statements.
>
> Both SQL statement within the UNION query must have the same number of fields, in same order in the result sets with similar data types.

http://www.techonthenet.com/sql/union.php

Answer (score 1):

You can use [UNION](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/union.html).

```
SELECT * FROM content WHERE myTable1 LIKE '% helo%'
UNION
SELECT * FROM myTable2 WHERE text LIKE '% helo%'
```

Comment: Still there is an error in my script, can you correct my work,

(SELECT * FROM WHERE content LIKE% hot helo%)
UNION
(SELECT * FROM analysis WHERE title LIKE% helo%)

Does the script above is true or if it is wrong please corrected.

Comment: @ukung Where is the table name in the first SELECT?

Comment: (SELECT * FROM hot WHERE content LIKE '%helo%') UNION (SELECT * FROM analisis WHERE title LIKE '%helo%')
Message Error : "#1222 - The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns". I dont know?

Comment: the individual queries in a union **MUST** return the same NUMBER of columns, and those columns MUST have the same type. if one query returns 5 varchars and the other returns 3 ints, the union will fail.

Comment: So it must be the same type and size of the field names?

Comment: @ukung Yes. You can correct this by using `(SELECT col1,col2...) UNION (SELECT col1,col2...)` instead of `SELECT *...`